# Redirection to Error-Page when OAuth2 fails?

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, oauth-2.0

I'm having an Angular Project which is using OAuth2 from [Manfred Steyer](https://manfredsteyer.github.io/angular-oauth2-oidc/docs/) and also ForgeRock AM.
I was thinking, if authentication somehow fails (wrong clientID, invalid scopes, ...) or even when the login fails, I want to navigate the user to a new component, which displays an error.
I noticed, that when I'm not authenticated, I get a blank page when navigating to the new component. When I programmatically use a wrong clientID, the ForgeRock AM displays the error, so there is no authentication. Did anyone try to do such an error page in combination with oauth2?

Comment: it depends on your code , if you put the error page component to the module which is checking Authorization then you cant see new component and you have to create new module which is not checking authorization